# Content Security Policy violation: JupytherHub within an iframe

Tags: jupyterhub

I'm loading jupyterhub within an iframe. The hub loads properly but the single user image does not due to the content security policy violation.

```
Refused to display 'http://localhost:30100/user/rabraham/tree?' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'".
```

Here is my `jupyterhub_config.file`, I'd appreciate any help or pointers:

```py
import os
c = get_config()
os.environ['OAUTH2_TOKEN_URL']= f"{os.environ['HOST_URL']}/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token"
from oauthenticator.generic import GenericOAuthenticator
c.JupyterHub.authenticator_class = GenericOAuthenticator

c.JupyterHub.authenticator_class.login_handler._OAUTH_AUTHORIZE_URL=f"{os.environ['HOST_URL']}/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth"

#c.GenericOAuthenticator.token_url = f"{os.environ['HOST_URL']}/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token"

c.OAuthenticator.login_service = "15Rock"
c.OAuthenticator.client_id = os.environ['CLIENT_ID']
c.OAuthenticator.client_secret = os.environ['CLIENT_SECRET']
c.OAuthenticator.token_url = f"{os.environ['HOST_URL']}/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token"
c.OAuthenticator.userdata_url = f"{os.environ['HOST_URL']}/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo"
c.OAuthenticator.userdata_method = 'GET'
c.OAuthenticator.userdata_params = {"state": "state"}
c.OAuthenticator.username_key = "preferred_username"

#c.Authenticator.auto_login=True
os.environ['OAUTH2_AUTHORIZE_URL']= f"{os.environ['HOST_URL']}/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth"
os.environ['OAUTH2_TOKEN_URL']= f"{os.environ['HOST_URL']}/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token"
os.environ['OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL']= f"{os.environ['NOTEBOOK_URL']}/hub/oauth_callback"
os.environ['OAUTH2_USERDATA_URL']= f"{os.environ['HOST_URL']}/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo"
c.Spawner.args = [f"--NotebookApp.tornado_settings={{\"headers\":{{\"Content-Security-Policy\": \"frame-ancestors 'self' {os.environ['HOST_URL']}\"}}}}"]
c.JupyterHub.tornado_settings = {
  'headers': {
    'Content-Security-Policy': f"frame-ancestors 'self' {os.environ['HOST_URL']}"
  }
}
c.NotebookApp.tornado_settings = {
  'headers': {
    'Content-Security-Policy': f"frame-ancestors 'self' {os.environ['HOST_URL']}"
  }
}


c.JupyterHub.cookie_secret = b'abc'

c.JupyterHub.spawner_class = 'dockerspawner.DockerSpawner'
spawn_cmd = os.environ.get('DOCKER_SPAWN_CMD', "start-singleuser.sh")
c.DockerSpawner.extra_create_kwargs.update({ 'command': spawn_cmd })

c.DockerSpawner.args = [f"--NotebookApp.tornado_settings={{\"headers\":{{\"Content-Security-Policy\": \"frame-ancestors 'self' {os.environ['HOST_URL']}\"}}}}"]
c.DockerSpawner.debug = True

notebook_dir = os.environ.get('DOCKER_NOTEBOOK_DIR') or '/home/jovyan/work'

c.DockerSpawner.notebook_dir = notebook_dir
c.DockerSpawner.image = os.environ['DOCKER_JUPYTER_CONTAINER']

c.DockerSpawner.http_timeout=600
# Mount the real user's Docker volume on the host to the notebook user's
# notebook directory in the container

c.DockerSpawner.volumes = { 'jupyterhub-user-{username}': notebook_dir }

## Docker spawner

network_name = os.environ['DOCKER_NETWORK_NAME']
c.DockerSpawner.network_name = network_name
c.DockerSpawner.use_internal_ip = True


# See https://github.com/jupyterhub/dockerspawner/blob/master/examples/oauth/jupyterhub_config.py

c.JupyterHub.hub_ip = 'jhub'
```